# Ideas on double posting / cross-posting policy

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know what do you think about questions that are being asked simultaneously here & on StackOverflow. I don't know what's the authors' idea, to get more visibility probably? Usually these questions are very localized and of little reuse value.

You can't mark them as duplicate because it's across the site boundaries. You could downvote them + comment, but on which site? You can vote to close or flag for moderator's attention...

Few recent examples:

[Unknown property 'String.plancount' visual force](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/unknown-property-string-plancount-visual-force) vs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809674/unknown-property-string-plancount-visual-force

[Prevent Duplicate History Record From Apex Trigger Modification](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/prevent-duplicate-history-record-from-apex-trigger-modification) vs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777606/prevent-duplicate-history-record-from-apex-trigger-modification

[End of day Data aggregation?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8155/end-of-day-data-aggregation) vs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735453/salesforce-how-to-get-conversation-history

To be clear: I'm not talking about genuine different sources that end up having same problem ([Salesforce Developer Workbench Hosted Version OAuth Error - Remote Access Authorization Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/salesforce-developer-workbench-hosted-version-oauth-error-remote-access-author) vs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509377/salesforce-api-oauth-authorization-error-1800). I find it annoying only when it's from same author and posted few minutes apart.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked in the StackExchange moderators' chat channel and the consensus is that you should vote to close one of the questions, leaving a comment to the effect that it's posted elsewhere. Pick the one that seems less 'at home'.

I've done the needful on these three questions.